# PHP While - Color change every time

Tags: php, css, colors, html-table, gradient

I have a PHP while loop, which displays the content of a database, in a table.
I would like to make all the rows in the table different colors.

But not just random. I would like them have different shades of red, where the first row is most red, and then the rest fades into a lighter red.

As an exemple, I would like the same effect as the iPhone App: Clear.
Photo example: http://www.realmacsoftware.com/_resources/clear/images/ss_pinch.png

I've tried to make the effect with -nth in CSS and some jQuery, but just couldn't figure it out. I hope you will give it a try.

Here is the code:

```
<table>


<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Navn:</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Spørgsmål:</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Tid:</strong></td>

</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['ask']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['time']; ?></td>


<?php
}
?>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You want a gradient. This isn't related to PHP.

Comment: You have any idea, how i could make the effect then?

Comment: CSS-only, gradient. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973179/css-rounded-table-corners-gradient-background)

Comment: @Cthulhu that won't create discrete colors

Comment: @JanDvorak `I would like them have different shades of red, where the first row is most red, and then the rest fades into a lighter red.` I assume this means a gradient.

Comment: @Cthulhu look at the image screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a different color for each element, then a static CSS file is not able to describe that. You could generate a CSS file on the fly, but I opt for inline styles instead. Don't use inline styles if you can use a static CSS file.

For a simple linear interpolaction from red to white, adhering to your coding style. I've also removed an extra `</div>` that didn't belong there:

```
<?php
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
$cur_row=0;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$color=intval(256*$cur_row/($num_rows-1));
$cur_row++;
?>
<tr style="background:rgb(256,<? echo $color.','.$color;>);">
<td><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['ask']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['time']; ?></td>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: When i try this, the result is just that the first row is red and the last is yellow. All the rows in between have no color?

Comment: @user1410965 added `intval` to prevent fractional values from appearing in the CSS style.

Comment: PERFECT! - That is exactly the effect i wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply css in table row.

```
<div class="grad">
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Navn:</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Spørgsmål:</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Tid:</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['ask']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['time']; ?></td>
</div>
 <?php
 }
?>
</tr>
</table>


<script>

//css Part
.grad
{
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000));
}
</script>
```

Comment: That won't create discrete colors.

Comment: You just change the left top , left bottom option only that's top bottom etc

Comment: Almost the effect i was looking for, except i would like every single row to have only one color. And the the next row, a color which is a bit lighter and so on.

Comment: Also, it won't work for firefox (but that's an easy fix) or IE8 (which can be not cared about)

Comment: Can you supply the Firefox Fix? - The IE problem doesn't exactly surprise me :)

Comment: @user1410965 note the `-webkit-` prefix? Create another line without a prefix for modern browsers, `-o-` for opera, `-ms-` for IE9+ and `-moz-` for Mozilla browsers. The latest versions of Opera and Firefox don't need the prefix. http://caniuse.com/css-gradients

Comment: Use this code for all browser. filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#996699’, endColorstr='#990000’); /* for IE */
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#996699), to(#990000)); /* for webkit browsers */ -moz-linear-gradient(top, #996699, #990000); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

Answer (score 1):

You can also play around with Javascript and HSV (which is a different 'color coordinate system').

Jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QXLRg/7/
Another demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QXLRg/8/
and another: http://jsfiddle.net/QXLRg/10/

(All I did, just change the 'h' value..)

```
var h = 0.4;
var s = 0.9;
var v = 0.95;
```

So, if you want to programatically create different colors then it's much better to use HSV instead of raw RGB, cause you can fine control for example 'the color mildness' and much more things.. as you can see in the above example

Comment: HSV is a good idea. Note that CSS also supports HSV so you can use PHP and you don't need JS :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$colors = array("yellow","red","green","silver");
$i=0;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr bgcolor="<?php echo $colors[$i]; ?>">
<td><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['ask']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['time']; ?></td>


<?php
$i<3?$i++:$i=0;
}
?>
```

replace like this if you want to rgb color mode then change color name to rgb scale such as rgb(100,100,100)

Comment: Switching this to use a for loop would simplify it.